# asciidoc: Return to Section after Subsection

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

I have the following document:

```
= Section
main text
== Subsection
some details text
```

Now I would like to continue my main text after the subsection. How can I "return" to the section part?

Differently speaking, how can I go up in the section hierarchy?
As far as I know, defining a new section, e.g., a `==` after a `=`, will bring me **down one hierarchy**. Is there also a way to go back **up one hierarchy**? I.e., to go back to the previous `=` level?
If I write `=` again, I start a new section, but I want to continue the old section, that already started before the current subsection.

I am imagining something like this:

```
= Section
main text
== Subsection
some details text
= (some keyword to return to the previous section)
continue main text
```

Comment: I am not sure on how the subsection is supposed to be visually separated to the section. My question would be: How does the reader knows, that the subsection is over and that he is back to the section?

Maybe a subsection is not what you are looking for and a block would be better. The content in "example" and "sidebar" blocks are visually separated from normal paragraphs for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can return to a "parent" section level by introducing a new parent heading, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/sections/titles-and-levels/).

Since there is no `some keyword to return to the previous section`, you cannot do:

```
== Section

Loreum ipsum...

=== Sub-section...

Ipso facto...

Parent section content here.
```

However, you could use one of the various blocks types to simulate that structure. Here's an example of using an open block with a discrete heading:

```
== Section

Lorem ipsum...

--
[discrete]
=== Sub-section

Ipso facto...
--

'''

Parent section content here.
```

The discrete heading is necessary to prevent the heading being counted as a sub-section title, which in turn would include the following parent section content within the sub-section. Note that using the discrete heading removes the heading from the table of contents too.

I included a horizontal rule with `'''` so that there is a visual delineation between the sub-section content and the parent section's continuing content.